# Simple random number generator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple Random number generator in Javascript. I am running into a problem, when submitting my form I am getting NaN. I can't seem to figure out why, I have tried to look around to find others number generator but still no luck. Hopefully one of you are able to help me, where I run into the problem.

```
const startNumber = document.getElementsByName("startNumber").value
const endNumber = document.getElementsByName("startNumber").value
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const form = document.getElementById("randomForm");

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let rTal = Math.floor(Math.random() * (endNumber - startNumber) + startNumber)
    output.innerHTML = rTal;
})
```

The concept, is that the user types in two values, a min number and a max in a input field - is this the right approach?

```
    <div id="randomGenerator">
        <div id="generatorText">
            Do you want to calculate a random number?
            <form id="randomForm">
                <input type="number" name="startNumber" class="numbers">
                <input type="number" name="endNumber" class="numbers">
                <input type="submit" value="Generate">
            </form>
            <div id="finalNumber">Your random number is</div>
            <div id="output"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Based on the comments so far, I have updated my code to this

```
const startNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("startNumber").valueAsNumber
const endNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("endNumber").valueAsNumber
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const form = document.getElementById("randomForm");

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let rTal = Math.floor(Math.random() * (endNumber - startNumber) + startNumber)
    output.innerHTML = rTal;
})
```

It still gives NaN as output

Comment: `.value` gives you the value as string. Try `.valueAsNumber` instead

Comment: Where did you assign any value to `startNumber`?

Comment: `const endNumber = document.getElementsByName("startNumber").value` - that doesn't work (apart from that you got "end" and "start" mixed up here) - getElementsByName returns a NodeList, and that doesn't have a value. You would need to access the first element in that list here first. `document.getElementsByName("startNumber")[0].value`

Comment: `const endNumber = document.getElementsByName("startNumber").value` wrong on three levels.... `getElementsByName` does not return a single element and if it would, you are reading it when the page renders and startNumber is not endNumber.

Comment: @CBroe I did that, I don't know why it didn't got uploaded. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are several mistakes you made:**

First of all, [.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) return *array* of DOM elements, not a single element you can get value from. So you should get value from first element in array using:

```js
document.getElementsByName("startNumber")[0].value
```

or using another method like [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which returns *one* element:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name=startNumber]')
```

Also, you possibly save wrong elements state when you declare `startNumber` & `endNumber` variables on top-level / outside of event listener. Try to access to elements inside of listener:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const startNumber = document.getElementsByName("startNumber")[0].value
  ...
})
```

**Working snippet below, check this out:**

```js
const form = document.getElementById("randomForm");

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const output = document.getElementById("output")
    const startNumber = document.getElementsByName("startNumber")[0].value
    const endNumber = document.getElementsByName("endNumber")[0].value
    const rTal = Math.floor(Math.random() * (endNumber - startNumber) + startNumber)
    output.innerText = rTal;
})
```

```html
<div id="randomGenerator">
    <div id="generatorText">
        Do you want to calculate a random number?
        <form id="randomForm">
            <input type="number" name="startNumber" class="numbers">
            <input type="number" name="endNumber" class="numbers">
            <input type="submit" value="Generate">
        </form>
        <div id="finalNumber">Your random number is</div>
        <div id="output"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped and it finally works. I guess i need to get a better understanding of getelementsbyName!

Comment: @EmilNoer you are welcome! Check out [.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) docs link for detailed info about method.

Comment: @EmilNoer you may consider accepting this as the correct answer then.

Comment: @LajosArpad done! Didn't know how to!

Comment: @EmilNoer thanks! I can perfectly understand you, but in general it is good to encourage people to accept the answers that helped them.

Answer (score 0):

`.value` These are string, they are not correct selectors either as per Xeelley's answer

```js
const startNumber = document.getElementsByName("startNumber").value
const endNumber = document.getElementsByName("startNumber").value
```

You need to parse them to a number format as one of the comments say you try to use [`.valueAsNumber`](https://caniuse.com/?search=valueasnumber), the other option is you wrap them in [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you only take whole numbers [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for floating-point numbers